# Is there a way to enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing for WordPress' ajaxurl?

Tags: jquery, javascript, headers

WordPress already has a default URL for jQuery-WordPress application calls and it's well known as the `ajaxurl`. However, there are cases wherein one would need to enable **Cross-Origin Resource Sharing** (CORS) on it such that any hostname will be able to access using it.

My current solutions is by adding a line in `/wp-includes/http.php` with:

```
@header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' );
```

Such that it will be:

### http.php

```
...
function send_origin_headers() {
    $origin = get_http_origin();

    @header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' );
    if ( is_allowed_http_origin( $origin ) ) {
        @header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' .  $origin );
        @header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );
        if ( 'OPTIONS' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] )
            exit;
        return $origin;
    }

    if ( 'OPTIONS' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {
        status_header( 403 );
        exit;
    }

    return false;
}
...
```

It works but editing the WordPress core is not a good solution.

Is there a better way to enable CORS for the `ajaxurl`?

## Warning

[This topic contains security vulnerabilities](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/26/copying-code-from-stack-overflow-you-might-be-spreading-security-vulnerabilities/) when actually implementing it on a wordpress installation.

## Note

This question was posted during the era of **Wordpress 4.3**. When the **Wordpress 4.4** was released with the new feature [WordPress REST API](https://wordpress.org/support/wordpress-version/version-4-4/#for-developers), enabling CORS no longer became necessary and instead just use the `rest_api_init` hook to [add custom REST endpoints](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/).

Comment: You want to call an api right?? Kind of json.?

Comment: @solai It will be used it to get response value from a specified `action` as per [AJAX in WordPress Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: OH.. So, You want to send request to diff domain. 
you want to call this url xxx.com/ajax.php from yyy.com? 
Right?

Comment: That's right @solai

Comment: If you look at source, both `get_http_origin` and `is_allowed_http_origin` have filters to let you manipulate their values.

Answer (score 18):

Milo is correct.

For instance, go to your theme's functions.php file, and add the following:

```
add_filter( 'allowed_http_origins', 'add_allowed_origins' );
function add_allowed_origins( $origins ) {
    $origins[] = 'https://site1.example.com';
    $origins[] = 'https://site2.example.com';
    return $origins;
}
```

Now an ajax call from https://site1.example.com to your site's ajax url will have the appropriate Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response. eg.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://site1.example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        ...
    },
    success: function(doc) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add this code into your function.php, no need to update `.htaccess`, `/wp-includes/http.php` or any other core file.

```
function just_add_cors_http_header($headers){

    $headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';

    return $headers;

}

add_filter('wp_headers','just_add_cors_http_header');
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by the following code.

Open you **header.php**

find the following text in that file

```
< !DOCTYPE html>
```

and replace it with the following.

```
<?php /** @package WordPress @subpackage Default_Theme  **/
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
?>
<! DOCTYPE html>
...
```

Now u can find Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * in your header.

Hope this helps..!Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The best way as far as I found, I followed this link .

*Just add the origin code to the WordPress **header.php** or ajax **functions/api** file.*

**Link:**  [https://stackoverflow.com/a/25719261/5431206]

Thanks