# Is it safe to fix Access-Control-Allow-Origin (CORS origin) errors with a php header directive?

Tags: headers, api, rest-api

I am trying to show a Formidable Pro Form from a WordPress site to the other.
I followed the developer's API and the REST API, but faced a CORS problem.

Then I found a suggestion on a forum thread suggesting to add this line of code the `functions.php` of the site where the original form is:

`header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

I tried this code and it worked perfectly fine.

My question is: does this code opens security risks or other vulnerabilities?

The solution seems too simple for a problem that faces many people.

Your input is highly appreciated.

Comment: @markratledge. Thanks for editing the question. It now makes more sense and certainly helped me to write better questions.

Comment: I wonder if this answer helps: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/226494/51462

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you open your site to being requested via AJAX to any other script in the whole web.

It would be better if you limit the origin to **one** specific remote domain from which you are consuming the API, like [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin):

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://mozilla.com");
```

However as the mozilla documentation states, a client can fork the origin, nevertheless limiting the sites a casual user can connect is a deterrent for some attacks.

Even better, you can limit your request to [only the methods you really need to allow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/20431/2162), the gist is this snippet, and it works for several domains, **if you have the `$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']` variable populated**:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function() {

     /* unhook default function */
     remove_filter('rest_pre_serve_request', 'rest_send_cors_headers');

     /* then add your own filter */
     add_filter('rest_pre_serve_request', function( $value ) {
          $origin = get_http_origin();
          $my_sites = array( 'http://site1.org/', 'http://site2.net', );
          if ( in_array( $origin, $my_sites ) ) {
              header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . esc_url_raw( $origin ) );
          } else {
              header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . esc_url_raw( site_url() ) );
          }
          header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET' );

          return $value;
     });
}, 15);
```

As you can see, this snippet uses the function [get_http_origin](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_http_origin/) provided by WordPress, but it will return null or empty, if the key `HTTP_ORIGIN` is not populated in the `$_SERVER` array, therefore it's not available to the PHP script, maybe because it is blocked by the cloudflare proxy you are using. I'd check quickly, with a script with the `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, if you have this variable populated.

Maybe the origin site it's populated in another header by cloudflare, and you could use it in a function hooked to the `http_origin` filter. If you are lost to this point, edit your original question posting the contents of the _SERVER variable, except your filesystem paths or passwords.

I'd be glad to help.

Comment: Thanks. The first solution worked for me. But since I have 4 sites that I want to allow them to access the main site, do I repeat the line 4 times and change the site url, or it can be combined into a single  command? thanks

Comment: Of course you can, I use to allow just a to a few sites access to the API, I've updated my answer with the check for this, if it works, would you mind to upvote the answer?

Comment: first solution 2orked for 1 domain only. if i repeated the line, it doesn't work. I tried the method in this thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains), but doesn't work too.
When I apply solution 2, this is what I get: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://coptic-treasures.com/wp-json/frm/v2/forms/6?return=html. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://coptic-treasures.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'https://audio.coptic-treasures.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: You can't use the Allow Origin header most than once. I've updated my answer with further instructions to help you debug the issue because always returning the same site shouldn't happen and it should recognize the list of your domains you pass to the array. Please update your question with the data of the $_SERVER variable, returned by `phpinfo()`, excluding passwords and filesystem paths. I'd be glad to help.

Comment: It's taken me about 2 days to find out how to remove CORS access from the WP-JSON API. Thanks for this. Remove the `rest_send_cors_headers` function call!

Comment: If that helped, would you consider upvote the answer?

Answer (score 1):

background - browsers are restricting remote access from scripts to only the site from which it was loaded. If this kind of check wasn't done, while visiting a site X it would have been possible for it to submit data to your gmail account (if you are logged in) without even needing to guess your user and password, because the browser would have sent the proper authentication cookies to gmail.

The CORS "protocol" is there to help you relax this restriction when needed.

So the question that you should ask yourself, is do I need it? On the one hand, I can't see why would 99% of wordpress sites need it, on the other hand, wordpress cookies are relatively short lived and 99% of wordpress sites are not going to be a target to such a random attack.

I would say, that since the rest API is a mutating one, and have access to private information, you should not use rest api in your solution if you need to enable cors, you better write your own "read only" API.

Comment: The OP is not talking about the 99% of WP sites out there, but their own sites, and according to the question its needed to make available resources from other site.

Comment: @JesúsFranco, and your point is?

Comment: That the point is **answer the question**, it is the goal of this site.

Comment: @JesúsFranco, I think my rep shows that I know how to answer questions and don't need your advice?

Comment: So, you have an specific idea of how the OP can resolve this problem?

Comment: @JesúsFranco, the OP asked if it is secure. the answer is that it is not. The solution is obviously not to do things that require you to use cors

Comment: My question is based on what do you state that there is a risk of access to private information. Actually one of the core tenants of the API it's that only the developer can give access to private information, as the API as its provided upstream doesn't.

Comment: @JesúsFranco As far as I know the API uses cookies for authentication and people with admin role for example can get almost any information. If you totally disable CORS and I am using some sort of phishing to get you into my site I can write JS that will perform any operation on your site, because **you are authenticated in it** and your browser will just send the authentication cookies as part of the request. I will not even need to guess your user name.... It is not even enough to block access to "write" end points as as an admin you can get classified info

Comment: It is possible that currently there isn't much that can be obtained with the API, but its goal is to be able to replace the whole admin, so it will have to serve to the client all of the existing data.

Comment: Thanks Mark, knowing the mechanism that can be abused to turn the API access to something insecure, is very helpful in order to think how to handle that risks, and then being able to decide if a patch can be used, limiting other way the uses if the methods usable to remote scripts, or writing a whole new API.

Comment: @MarkKaplun I am new to WP-API so I had a question. Would allowing CORS for only 'GET' methods also expose the server to vulnerabilities?

Comment: @shariqkhan, this is probably best asked on SO or the security stack, but in general, the answer is yes. CORS should be disabled only for sites you trust or on subdomains of yours that do not do any action without authorization credentials being send in the body of the request. As long as the rest api uses cookies for authentication and it runs on the same domain as the WP site, you should be very careful with disabling it.

Comment: but again, if you disable CORS only for one specific URL that you know it will not be able to be used to do any harm, than it might be OK. It is not so much a matter of GET vs POST, but what is it that is actually being done at that end point

Comment: Thanks @MarkKaplun, I have seen your many answers on SO/SE so I know that you know what you are talking about, I will probably ask it on SO, though I feel the question may get closed as being 'too broad' or as a 'duplicate'.
I am intrigued as how various websites like Github, Twitter (and many WordPress based sites too) etc open their APIs by disabling CORS restrictions for everyone. I was under the impression that if you are disabling CORS  for just GET requests, it is pretty harmless because you are just allowing others to fetch data and not modifying anything?

Comment: The difference between wordpress and other sites is that they do not use cookie based authentication for the API, and the usage of the API require sending user and password style information explicitly in each request. WordPress API <rant alert> was badly designed in that regard, and probably could not be designed better since it had to supports insecure communication over HTTP which prevented it from using the user/password technique as anyone listening on a (for example) WiFi would have discovered the values.

Comment: the fact that you have the cookies set when you are logged in is what attackers can exploit to send AJAX request as if the originated by you. With CORS on, such requests will fail for other domains, and since you are the only one that controls the domain you are safe. The more site for which you disable CORS, the more places which an attacker can take control of, and attack you by enticing you to go on that site. The question was about fully disabling CORS for all sites, which is very bad, but if you disable it for other domain that you fully control, while not be a great thing, is not as bad.