# Default Wordress RSS Widget does not work on a subdomain site, works when I move it

Tags: feed

I'm having problems with the default RSS Widget that takes in a RSS feed and spits it out to the viewer.

I created an RSS feed on my main domain.  I know it works because I'm use the w3 feed validator and it validates. Both systems are on IIS.

On my subdomain, I have a wordpress install. When I add in that RSS address from my main domain, I get the following:

```
RSS Error: WP HTTP Error: A valid URL was not provided.
```

If I move the RSS file to the subdomain, the RSS widget then works. Any suggestions on why cross origin is not working?

Also if I use feedburner to feed in my RSS feed and use the feedburner rss, it works.

Comment: This might be related and might help you: [Is there a way to enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing for WordPress' ajaxurl?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/198943/is-there-a-way-to-enable-cross-origin-resource-sharing-for-wordpress-ajaxurl)

Comment: I will take a look. Why do outside feeds like feedburner work ?